# In Twilio is it possible to Gather and Record simultaneously?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In twilio response I can usually record an conversation and transcribe it. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
 <Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/transcribe"/>
</Response>
```

However I am interested to do the same with new speech option for `Gather`. e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Gather input="speech" action="/completed">
       <Say>Welcome home!</Say>
   </Gather>
</Response>
```

However, though I can get the transcription in `/completed` handler `SpeechResult` parameter, I am unable to record gathered speech simultaneously. Is there any way I can use `Record` along with `Gather` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot use [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) and [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) together, as you have discovered.

The only way I can think of that you could use to record the whole call, as well as doing the speech recognition parts is if you are [generating the call yourself from the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). The you could set the [`Record` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) to true when making the call. This would record the entire call.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: what is the difference between Gather with input=speech and Record with transcribe=true

Comment: `<Gather>` with `input="speech"` will return a `SpeechResult` parameter to your `action` URL in real time using the Google Cloud Speech API. There is also a maximum of 60 seconds transcribing in this way. Using `<Record>` with `transcribe="true"` will happen asynchronously, can be used on recordings of up to 120 seconds and will store the recording and transcription text for later. Basically, `<Gather>` is for live transcription and speech recognition and `<Record>` is for storing the result for later.

Comment: ok, but as far as Speech conversion to text is concerned, there is no difference apart from length of speech, right? Both are powered by Google Cloud Speech API?

Comment: No, the Record transcription pre-dates Google Cloud Speech.

Comment: ohh, using Record i can choose which STT service to use(IBM Watson, or Google Cloud Speech), but with Gather it is fixed to use Google Cloud Speech. right?

Comment: You can do that by passing your recording to those services yourself, I don’t actually know the service that Twilio uses for transcription if you select `transcribe=“true”`.

Comment: @philnash : So just to confirm i cannot use other STT services of our choice for  <gather>. For <gather> the input transcribe will be always done by twilio?